# mapa do google do android no meu app

Tags: android

Eu estou começando agora a criar meu primeiro app em android já criei apps para outras plataformas, então que queria sabe como eu coloco o mapa do google ou do bing em meu app.

Answer (score 2):

Depois de ler a tua pergunta apenas me dirigi ao [Google](http://google.com) e em menos de 10 segundos encontrei isto: https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html. Lê com atenção que diz tudo ai.

**EDIT:**

Para ser mais preciso e nao andares "perdido" a procura deixo-te aqui o seguinte trecho de código disponivel na pagina que te sugeri.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206); /* AQUI A ALTITUDE E LONGITUDE */

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney") /* TITULO DA CIDADE */
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.") /* LABEL OU SEJA, UMA PEQUENA DESCRIÇÃO */
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

Cumprimentos,
thecreator

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira rápida, para você que é iniciante, é criar uma Google Maps Activity

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela já gera um .xml para você inserir a chave do maps e já te fornece um link de como gerar essa chave.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais informações no Getting Started do Google Maps V2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda fico muito grato